# Code seems to be stuck in a potential loop

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, java.util.scanner, user-input

I am writing an answer to a CCC question in java, but every time I input something it just takes infinite inputs. Can anyone help me stop this?

> Your task is to write a program that verifies the validity of a well plan by verifying that the borehole will not intersect itself. A two-dimensional well plan is used to represent a vertical cross-section of the borehole, and this well plan includes some drilling that has occurred starting at `(0, −1)` and moving to `(−1, −5)`. You will encode in your program the current well plan shown in the figure below:
>
> **Input Format:**
>
> The input consists of a sequence of drilling command pairs. A drilling command pair begins with one of four direction indicators (`d` for down, `u` for up, `l` for left, and `r` for right) followed by a positive length. There is an additional drilling command indicated by q (quit) followed by an integer, which indicates the program should stop the execution. You can assume that the input is such that the drill point will not:
>
> - rise above the ground, nor
> - be more than 200 units below ground, nor
> - be more than 200 units to the left of the original starting point, nor
> - be more than 200 units to the right of the original starting point.
>
> **Output Format:**
>
> The program should continue to monitor drilling assuming that the well shown in the figure has already been made. As we can see `(−1, −5)` is the starting position for your program. After each command, the program must output one line with the coordinates of the new position of the drill, and one of the two comments `safe`, if there has been no intersection with a previous position or `DANGER` if there has been an intersection with a previous borehole location. After detecting and reporting a self-intersection, your program must stop.

My code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> holeX = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> holeY = new ArrayList<>();
        String direction;
        boolean danger = false;
        holeX.add(0);
        holeX.add(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            holeX.add(i);
        }
        holeX.add(3);
        holeX.add(3);
        holeX.add(4);
        holeX.add(5);
        holeX.add(5);
        holeX.add(5);
        holeX.add(6);
        for (int i = -3; i > -8; i--) {
            holeX.add(7);
        }
        for (int i = 6; i > -2; i--) {
            holeX.add(i);
        }
        holeX.add(-1);
        holeX.add(-1);

    holeY.add(-1);
    holeY.add(-2);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        holeY.add(-3);
    }
    holeY.add(-4);
    holeY.add(-5);
    holeY.add(-5);
    holeY.add(-5);
    holeY.add(-4);
    holeY.add(-3);
    holeY.add(-3);
    for (int i = -3; i > -8; i--) {
        holeY.add(i);
    }
    for (int i = 6; i > -2; i--) {
        holeY.add(-7);
    }
    holeY.add(-6);
    holeY.add(-5);

    do {
        direction = sc.next();
        int steps = sc.nextInt();
        switch (direction) {
            case "d":
                for (int i = holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1); i > holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1) - steps; i--) {
                    holeY.add(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < holeY.size() - 2; j++) {
                        if (Objects.equals(holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1), holeY.get(j)) && Objects.equals(holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1), holeX.get(j))) {
                            danger = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            case "u":
                for (int i = holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1); i < holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1) + steps; i++) {
                    holeY.add(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < holeY.size() - 2; j++) {
                        if (Objects.equals(holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1), holeY.get(j)) && Objects.equals(holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1), holeX.get(j))) {
                            danger = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "l":
                for (int i = holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1); i > holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1) - steps; i--) {
                    holeX.add(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < holeX.size() - 2; j++) {
                        if (Objects.equals(holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1), holeX.get(j)) && i == holeY.get(j)) {
                            danger = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "r":
                for (int i = holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1); i < holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1) + steps; i++) {
                    holeX.add(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < holeX.size() - 2; j++) {
                        if (Objects.equals(holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1), holeX.get(j)) && i == holeY.get(j)) {
                            danger = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (danger == false && !"q".equals(direction)) {
            System.out.println(holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1) + " " + holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1) + "safe");
            System.out.print(" safe");
        } else {
            System.out.println(holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1) + " " + holeY.get(holeY.size() - 1) + " DANGER");
        }
    } while (!"q".equals(direction) && danger == false);
}
```

`holeX` and `holeY` are the coordinates of the drilled area.

**Input:**

```
l 2
d 2
r 1
q 0
```

**Output:**

```
-3 -5 safe
-3 -7 safe
-2 -7 safe
```

Comment: What's the sense of your loop going from `-3` to `-7` and always adding `7`?

Comment: Also, the indentation of half of your `main`-method is wrong!

Comment: do you really care about that dude and also the starting **y** coordinate is `-3` while the last one is `-7`, but the **x** coordinate stays the same

Comment: Of course I care about that and you will as well once you start learning Python. Indentation is crucial for readability. And for the second half: yes, exactly that was my question. Why are you going from `-3` to `-7`?

Comment: -3 to -7 is the y coordinate and stack overflow killed my indentation

Comment: I don't think so. Half of your `main` is indented differently than the other half!

Comment: cuz StackOverflow killed my indentation

Comment: Can you refactor the code please

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, you have an infinite loop. Let's take `case "l"` for example.

I used `l` and then `2`.

`for (int i = holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1); i > holeX.get(holeX.size() - 1) - steps; i--) {
holeX.add(i)...`

You add something to the list and the condition gets re-evaluated, which leads to an infinite loop.

I don't know if it is what you want to do, but what helps is to extract the condition first into a variable, then the infinite loop stops.

Comment: btw, its l not 1

Comment: Yes I wrote l (the letter), but the with the code font it looks like the number 1